# INetCache/IE folder contains an incredible amount of files and consumes a lot of disk space?

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, disk-space, wiztree

By using WizTree I discover that inside [`INetCache\IE` folder](https://www.lifewire.com/find-and-view-temporary-internet-files-in-ie-818231), there are around 5 million ++ files, and they consume 11.3 GB.

[image]

This is strange because

1. I don't use Internet Explorer on my Windows 10 machine, so where the files come from?
2. When I go to the `INetCache\IE` folder, even if I turn on to see all the protected file system and the hidden files, I can only see a handful files and they only consume something like 4MB.

Where the rest of the files/hard disk go? **Can ( or How can) I delete the contents to free up more space for my C Drive**?

Comment: As for the reason there is an IE folder, any application that has the capacity of downloading content throw a browser component that is based on the Trident engine would use that cache.  You should be able to delete the contents directly from WIzTree.

Comment: @Ramhound, what if I download things from Google Chrome/Firefox? They will also go to the IE folder? Doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Neither of those uses the Trident browser engine.

Comment: So that means I don't use the trident browser engine, which begs the question _who is writing to that folder_ ?

Comment: Any application that uses it that displays web content uses it, for instance, Visual Studio before 2019 and 2022 used it. Looking at the path, something is odd, AppData shouldn’t be in the Windows directory.

Comment: @Ramhound, nothing odd about it, see [here](https://www.lifewire.com/find-and-view-temporary-internet-files-in-ie-818231). What _is_ odd is that why the protected, invisible files are so numerous and consume so much space.

Comment: Is there anyway to check what are the invisible files? I need to know what files cause the excessive disk usage and get the app developers to fix this.

Comment: These files are in the system profile, not your user profile. That means some service (running as Local System, Local Service or Network Service) is using IE or IE components to do stuff.

Comment: This thread might help you: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c0835f0-efd5-4c1b-ac43-a1f27d8144f2/deleting-tempory-internet-files-system32?forum=winservergen

Answer (score 4):

The folder
`C:\Windows\System32\Config\SystemProfile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\`
caches temporary Internet Explorer files.

Although Microsoft does not want us to use the user interface of IE,
the engine still takes part in the Windows API and so is still used
by many programs.

Knowing which program produced these millions of file would require
examining the files. If you posted some of them, it might be possible
to guess the program that does this.

You could delete these files (I just deleted mine), where
the file `container.dat` should be skipped.
Or you could in Explorer right-click the C disk, select Properties
and click Disk Clean-up, select "Temporary Internet Files"
(and maybe some others) and click OK.

To avoid having these files in the first place, do the following.

**Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed**

- Run *Start > Internet Options*
- Position to the Advanced tab
- Place a check-mark next to
  "Empty Temporary Internet Files folder when browser is closed"
- Click OK.

This setting should in theory cause the IE engine to delete its
temporary files when closing.

If this does not solve the problem, see the following.

**Running a cleanup task**

The cleanup task can be run as a PowerShell script, contained in a `.ps1`
file. The contents of the file can be:

```
Remove-item "$env:systemroot\System32\Config\SystemProfile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\*.*" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Remove-item "$env:systemroot\SysWOW64\Config\SystemProfile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\IE\*.*" -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

You may run the file manually, or use the Task Scheduler
to run it daily. There are many sources to be found on the subject,
for example
[How to create an automated task using Task Scheduler on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10).

Comment: Do you use WizTree to check the folder size ? If so you will find that what you can see and can delete is just a fraction of the actual disk size used. I've included screenshot and addresses this point already in my question.

Comment: I now installed and ran WizTree. On my computer the size is exactly that of the files I can see. Have you tried to run `chkdsk` (without `/f` parameter)?

Comment: @Graviton To access all files in system folders, you must run the program as administrator.

Comment: @DanielB: I didn't need admin permissions to see or delete these files. I had about 140 MB.

Comment: @harrymc You have non-standard permissions then. The _config_ folder is not accessible for regular users, and neither are its contents of course.

Comment: @DanielB: No, I haven't changed any permissions, only my account is administrator.

Comment: Unless elevated (as in UAC), _every_ account is a regular user. Windows Explorer will by default also never run elevated. So, again: You absolutely do need admin rights to access and modify data in the _config_ folder.

Comment: @DanielB: I never change permissions in the registry.